# Hard disk failure after dual boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, upgrade, 18.04, hard-drive

I'm using a 500 GB HDD and upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. Today I installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on USB easily, but all of a sudden after USB bootup my 500GB HDD has vanished.

I tried checking through "DISKS" but cannot see physical presence. I need to get the HDD back to show. The hard disk seems to be OK, no noise etc. Healthy. I need step-by-step instructions because I am using a live USB here and I cannot afford to lose data.

Phoenix BIOS (Lenovo B570e). Will the drive work if I plug it in another laptop as external USB drive (USB caddy)?

Below are the current results of `sudo fdisk -l` (with loop devices removed):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 14.9 GiB, 15938355200 bytes, 31129600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00794104

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       64 31129599 31129536 14.9G  b W95 FAT32

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab
overlay / overlay rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

Comment: can you see it with sudo fdisk -l

Comment: If you really cannot afford to lose data, you have really good multiple backups. Drives do fail.  Does UEFI/BIOS see drive? If not check connections and maybe replace cables.

Comment: "after USB bootup, my 500 GB HDD has vanished" This seems normal if you have not mounted the HDD yet.

Comment: If the BIOS/UEFI doesn't see the drive, then this is a hardware issue.